# How to run a package that was installed with `python3 -m pip install ...`?

Tags: python, pip

I have installed the jupyter notebook with a command like this one:

`python3.6 -m pip install notebook`

It proceeds without issue.

Now I want to run it, if you use *traditional* pip, you get a simlink somewhere that allows you to just run the binary of the module. In this case that would be:

`jupyter notebook`

But that doesn't work for obvious reasons.

I tried looking for something like: `python3.6 -m pip run notebook`, but that doesn't exist.

I have found where the module files reside (`.local/lib/python...`) but I haven't been able to find a way to run it from there.

How should I run this now?

PS. I'm not looking for *something else* or finding *an alternative way to run the jupyter notebook*. I want to know how I may be able to run this thing **as it is right now**. This because I want to learn more about the behavior of pip in this situation.

Comment: `python3.6 -m jupyter`?  or just add the corresponding `bin` directory (`dirname $(command -v python3.6)`) to you `$PATH` (to use just `jupyter` without `python -m`).

Comment: Thanks @jfs, `python3.6` is on `/usr/bin` and there's no `jupyter` binary there.

Comment: `--user` became default recently (pip 20+) if global site-packages is non-writable -- there might be differences depending on Linux distribution. Make sure `$USER_BASE/bin` is in `$PATH` too (see `python3.6 -m site`).